# Cross-site communication - How its possible. Need a better Idea

Tags: asp.net

1. A link will be provided for the WebSiteA to WebSiteB
2. We are not able to code anything in WebSiteA
3. I need to pass a token from WebSiteA to WebSiteB (In order to understand the user is coming from WebSiteA)
4. Can't use `Request.UrlReferrer` to identify previous site since WebSiteA is HTTPS
5. Query string is insecure because of replay attack (If any outside get the url it can be re-used)

Comment: 2. We are not able to code anything in WebSiteA .... Do you mean you cant add / modify any code on website A ?

Comment: The key question is how WebsiteA identify the user? What kind of login mechanism does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally use an encrypted `POST` variable which get's POST'ed to WebSiteB.

WebSiteB then decrypts this with the private key.

Optional validation: WebSiteA has a (HTTPS?) webservice, which WebSiteB then checks with the decrypted key to validate / get more information from WebSiteA for that same request.

Some encryption / decryption techniques here: [Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)

This way it's secure and can be checked if it's trying to be spoofed etc...